# Prove that in any group an element and its inverse have same order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Prove that an element and its inverse have same order in any group.

Comment: Hint: $(g^{-1})^k = (g^k)^{-1}$

Comment: @ user114830: You have to show what you tried first so people can gauge where you stand and help you accordingly.

Comment: the cycle group generated by g has $g^{-1}$ as an element ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen : I am sorry but i could not understand what you mean.... +1 at manasi

Comment: @YACP Do you really think mine was an answer warranting a downvote? If the definition of order is, as I like to do, the number of elements in the generated subgroup, then that's a full answer, but of course almost trivial; if the definition is based on what power gives the identity (as, unfortunately, is usually spelled out), then it's no more than a hint.

Comment: @arbautjc It's technically off-topic for the reasons explained below; the OP should add details about his/her work on the subject, in order to make the question more helpful for future readers.

Comment: "Ok, but then many questions would be" Yes, and many are. "As long as it's mathematically sound" No (read the guidelines).

Comment: [An element of a group has the same order as its inverse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse)

Answer (score 2):

Since $g^{-1}\in \langle g\rangle$, we have that 
$$\langle g^{-1}\rangle\subseteq\langle g\rangle$$
For the same reason
$$\langle g\rangle\subseteq\langle g^{-1}\rangle$$

The order of an element $g$ is infinite if $\langle g\rangle$ is infinite, otherwise it's the same as $|\langle g\rangle|$ (number of elements).

Answer (score 1):

$$(g^{-1})^{o(g)}=(g^{o(g)})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$$
proves that $o(g^{-1})\leq o(g)$.

$$g^{o(g^{-1})}=((g^{-1})^{-1})^{o(g^{-1})}=((g^{-1})^{o(g^{-1})})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$$
proves that $o(g)\leq o(g^{-1})$

Comment: +1. Note that you can stop after the first step and invoke symmetry.