# An element of a group has the same order as its inverse

Tags: group-theory, faq

> If $a$ is a group element, prove that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same order.

I tried doing this by contradiction.

Assume $|a|\neq|a^{-1}|$.

Let $a^n=e$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(a^{-1})^m=e$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, and we can assume that $m < n$.

Then $e= e*e = (a^n)((a^{-1})^m) = a^{n-m}$. However, $a^{n-m}=e$ implies that $n$ is not the order of $a$, which is a contradiction and $n=m$.

But I realized this doesn’t satisfy the condition if $a$ has infinite order. How do I prove that piece?

Comment: Note that this is exercise 4 in chapter 3 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Comment: If you know that the order of an element equals the order of the subgroup generated by it, you just have to know that an element generates the same subgroup as its inverse (as it and its inverse are contained in the subgroup generated by the other).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794098/let-g-be-a-group-and-a-belongs-to-g-prove-that-langle-a-1-rangle

Answer (score 15):

Let $a^n$ be $e$, then $e=(aa^{-1})^n=a^n(a^{-1})^n=e(a^{-1})^n=(a^{-1})^n$.

Let $(a^{-1})^n=e$, then $e=(aa^{-1})^n=a^n(a^{-1})^n=a^ne=a^n$.

So, $a^n=e \iff (a^{-1})^n=e$.

Comment: Again,this is true only if the elements have finite order,so this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: not really, it clearly implies that $a$ has finite order if and only if $a^{-1}$ has finite order.

Comment: $\left(aa^{-1}\right)^n=a^n\left(a^{-1}\right)^n$ if and only if $G$  is abelian, right?

Comment: @Traveler no, because $a$ and $a^{-1}$ commute

Comment: @Jorge Fernández Hidalgo because they commute means? I am not following what you said. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @darshan they commute means that $x \cdot x^{-1} = x^{-1} \cdot x$, for all $x$.

Comment: Doesn't this only prove $|a^{-1}| \leq |a|$

Comment: @ssp He proved that $|a^{-1}| \leq |a|$ then that $|a| \leq |a^{-1}|$

Answer (score 9):

Suppose that $a$ has infinite order. We show that $a^{-1}$ cannot have finite order. Suppose to the contrary that $(a^{-1})^m=e$ for some positive integer $m$. We have by repeated application of associativity that
$$a^m (a^{-1})^m=e.$$
It follows that $a^m=e$.

Comment: But this proof doesn't really answer the question either since all it proves is that a and a-1 both have infinite order-it doesn't show they have the SAME order,which is what the claim is trying to prove in the case where the order isn't finite!

Comment: OP took care of the case $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have finite order. So it remains to deal with infinite order. The proof above shows that if $a$ has infinite order so does $a^{-1}$. The same argument applied to $a^{-1}$ shows that if $a^{-1}$ has infinite order so does $a$. Two elements of infinite order have the same order.

Comment: Ok,sorry,I missed something,I see it now. My bad. I have an alternate proof below.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say
a is an element and n is its order ,then
$$a^n=e$$
Repeatedly multiplication by $a^{-1}$ n times
$$(a^{-1})^{n}•(a)^{n}=e•(a^{-1})^n$$
$$(a^{-1}•a)^{n}=(a^{-1})^n$$
$$e^n=(a^{-1})^n=e$$
Hence "a" 's inverse is also having order of n.

Comment: You can only go from line 2 to 3 if $a$ and $a^{-1}$ commute. (Which they do.)

Comment: This answer merely shows that the order of $a^{-1}$ divides $n$. You also need to demonstrate that $k < n \implies (a^{-1})^k \neq e$.

Comment: You only proved that the order of $a^{-1}$
 was smaller than the order of $a$

Answer (score 0):

It seems a more straightforward solution exists?

If $g$ has infinite order then so does $g^{-1}$ since otherwise, for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $(g^{-1})^m=e=(g^m)^{-1}$, which implies $g^m=e$ since the only element whose inverse is the identity is the identity. This contradicts that $g$ has infinite order, so $g^{-1}$ must have infinite order.

If $g$ has finite order $n$, then by existence of inverses in a group $$g^n=e\iff$$ $$g^n \cdot (g^{-1})^n=e\cdot(g^{-1})^n\iff$$ $$g^n\cdot g^{-n}=(g^{-1})^n\iff$$ $$ e = (g^{-1})^n$$ This implies $|g^{-1}|\leq n$.

If $|g^{-1}|<n$, say $m$, then $(g^{-1})^m=e=(g^m)^{-1}\implies g^m=e$, which contradicts that $|g|=n>m$. So $|g^{-1}|=n$ if $|g|=n$.