# Prove that the order of an element $g$ in $G$ is equal to the order of its inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering if the following proof looks okay.

*Proof*. Let $g$ be any element of a group $G$. Then by definition, the order of $g$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $g^{n}=e$. We define the order of the element $g$ as $|g|=n$. Now, we wish to show that in any group, an element and its inverse have the same order.

For the inverse of the group element g,

$(g^{-1})^{n}=g^{-n}=(g^{n})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$.

Since the order of $g^{-1}$ is the least positive integer $m$ such that $(g^{-1})^{m}=e$, it follows that $|g^{-1}|\le |g|=n$.

Likewise, $((g^{-1})^{-1})^{m})=(g^{-1})^{-m}=(g^{-m})^{-1}=((g^{m})^{-1})^{-1}=(e^{-1})^{-1}=e$

Then since $(g^{-1})^{-1}=g$, $|g|\le |g^{-1}|.$

Therefore, the order of $g$ is equal to the order of its inverse. QED

Comment: Please do not as for proof-verification unless you have some concrete question about your proof. If you have a proof of a problem with no problems you're aware of, post it as a self-answered question. But first search to see if the question has been asked before, and put the solution *there*. In this case, that might be [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1008610/29335). If you find that nobody has asked the question, then self-answering is the way to go.

Comment: I love these kinds of proofs, where we have $F(f(f(a))=a)\ge F(f(a))\ge F(a)$ therefore $F(f(a))=F(a)$. Elegant.

Comment: I would like to ask at this point: the line that contains "it follows that ord(g^-1) < ord(g) = n", why does that conclusion follow?

Bit stuck here when trying to follow this proof, otherwise it is a very nicely put together proof.

Comment: @thesmallprint: If a group element $g$ has an order of $n$, then it follows that if $g^{k}=e$, for some $k \in \mathbb {Z^+}$, then $n$ divides $k$. So, applying it to the proof above, $(g^{-1})^{n}=e$ and $|g^{-1}|=m$. Then we have that $m$ divides $n$, so it must be that $m\leqslant n$.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay for me.

Maybe it could be shortened observing it is enough to prove that
$$ \forall n,\quad g^n=1\implies \bigl(g^{-1}\bigr){}^n=1. $$

Answer (score 0):

Once you've shown that $(g^{-1})^n=e$, you could just argue that if the order of $g^{-1}$ were actually $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$, with $m<n$, then
\begin{align}
g^n &= e\\
(g^{-1})^mg^n&=e\\
g^{n-m}&=e
\end{align}
but since $n-m<n$, this is a contradiction, since $n$ was the smallest natural number such that $g^n=e$. Hence $n$ is also the smallest natural number such that $(g^{-1})^n=e$.