# Order of an element and its inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> For $x$ an element in $\mathbb{G}$, show that $x$ and $x^{-1}$ have the same order.

$\mathbb{G}$ is a group, let $|x|=n\;$ and $\;|x^{-1}|=m$. We will show that $\;m=n\;$. We can show that by using the definition of division. Namely, if $\;n\mid m\;$ and $m\mid n\;$ then $\;n=m$.

Let $\;|x|=n\;$ that is $\;x^n=e\;$ and $n$ is the least positive integer by definition. And also, $\;(x^{-1})^m=e\;$ so by theorem (written below),

$$\;n\mid -m \rightarrow n\mid m.\tag{$*$}$$

Let $\;|x^{-1}|=m\;$ that is $\;(x)^{-m}=e\;$ and $m$ is the least positive integer by definition. And also, $x^n=e$ so again by theorem,

$$-m\mid n \rightarrow m\mid n.\tag{$**$}$$

Using $(*)$ and $(**)$ we get:

$$n=m$$

That is $x$ and $x^{-1}$ have the same order.

Is this solution valid? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. A quickest way is to prove that $x^k = e \Longleftrightarrow (x^{-1})^k=e$, so you get directly that $\min \lbrace k > 0, x^k=e \rbrace = \min \lbrace k > 0, (x^{-1})^k=e \rbrace $.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This way is too smooth, like that!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2794247/589