# Calculating the order of an power element in a group

Tags: group-theory

Trying to understand the group order material. While practising, I came across with the following question.

> Consider $g\in G$ so $o(g)=15$. calculate $o(g^7),o(g^{-1})$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I understand from $o(g)=15$ that $g^{15}=e$. So in order to calculate $o(g^5)$ we will have to do some arithmetic on $g^{15}$. we need to find $k\in\mathbb{N}$ so $(g^7)^k = e$. We are getting $g^{7k}=e$ and now I'm not sure what do next. Also probably the bigger problem is to understand how to calculate $o(g^{-1})$.

Comment: When does $12\mid5k$? For $g^{-1}$ it's even simpler... $g^{-k}=e$ iff $g^k=e$

Comment: @Federico Thanks for the replay. why $12|5k$?

Comment: $g^k=e$ iff $12\mid k$. Now, to find when $g^{5k}=e$, you have to find when $12\mid5k$.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion $\operatorname{ord}(g)=12$ means **two** things:

1. $g^{12}=e$;
2. if $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,11\}$, then $g^k\neq e$.

A standard fact about the order of an element is this: $g^k=e\implies\operatorname{ord}(g)\mid k$.

From the fact that $g^{12}=e$, you deduce that $(g^5)^{12}=e$, since$$(g^5)^{12}=g^{5\times12}=(g^{12})^5=e^5=e.$$Therefore, $\operatorname{ord}(g^5)$ is *at most* $12$.

Now, take $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,11\}$ and assume that $(g^5)^k=e$. This means that $g^{5k}=e$. But then, since $\operatorname{ord}(g)=12$, $12\mid5k$. Since $\gcd(12,5)=1$, it follows that $12\mid k$, which is impossible, since $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,11\}$. This proves that $\operatorname{ord}(g^5)=12$.

Now, prove that $\operatorname{ord}(g^{-1})$ is also equal to $12$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the order of $g^{-1}$ ("probably the bigger problem"), then everything is fine. It is easy to see that $o(g)=o(g^{-1})$:

[An element of a group has the same order as its inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse)

For the first question, by Lagrange, the order of the subgroup generated by an element divides the order of the group.