# Construct a group that has exactly 5 elements of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Construct a group that has exactly 5 elements of order 4.

I wonder if it is possible. I tried $U(8)$ but it has $\{[1], [3], [5],[7]\}$ as elements which has order $4$ but it has only $4$ elements. So I am quite stuck.

Answer (score 5):

[An element has the same order as its inverse.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse)

The inverse operation pairs off elements, except for those which are their own inverse.

Elements which are their own inverse have order 1 or 2.

Conclusion: elements of order 4 (or any other order greater than 2) come in pairs. It's not possible to have exactly 5.