# Proof that an element and its inverse have the same order in a group.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, inverse

I just want to make sure I'm alright on this proof and whether the contradiction is necessary. In some of the proofs  I've checked here they simply show that $x^n = 1$ to conclude that $|x| = n$, but shouldn't we also need to show that it's the minimal such integer as I've tried to do below?

**Prop:** Let $x \in G$, show that $|x| = |x^{-1}|$.

*Proof:* Assume that $|x| = n < \infty$, then we have that $(x^{-1})^n = (x)^{-n} = (x^n)^{-1} = 1$. Therefore it remains to show that $n$ is the minimal such integer. Assume for contradiction that $\exists \; r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $(x^{-1})^r = 1$ with $r < n$. Then by the similar logic to before
$$
\begin{align}
(x^{-1})^r &= 1 \\
x^r\cdot(x^r)^{-1} &= x^r \cdot1 \\
1 &= x^r.
\end{align}
$$
But this contradicts the minimality of $n$ as $|x| = n$. If $|x| = \infty$, then assume for contradiction that $|x|^{-1} = k < \infty$. Identically to the above we can arrive at
$$
\begin{align}
(x^{-1})^k &= 1 \\
x^k\cdot(x^k)^{-1} &= x^k \cdot1 \\
1 &= x^k.
\end{align}
$$
which contradicts that $x$ is of infinite order.

Is it unnecessary to use the contradictions, if so what's a hint at the direct proof?

Comment: Looks elegant enough to me

Comment: It's fine. Another approach is from $(x^{-1})^n = (x^n)^{-1}$ you can conclude $|x| \le |x^{-1}|$. And then swap the roles of $x$ and $x^{-1}$ to get equality.

Comment: Looks cool to me

Comment: Another approach (not by contradiction) for the case when $x$ has finite order. Let $|x|=n$. Then, since inverses are unique, $x^{-1} = x^{n-1}$. Note that $x^{k} = 1$ iff $k|n$ and $(n-1)$ and $n$ are coprime, so we must have $n \mid |x^{n-1}|$. Furthermore, $n$ suffices, so we find that $|x^{n-1}| = |x^{-1}| = n$.

Comment: For a direct proof, see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse).

Comment: Note that $a^k=e\iff (a^{-1})^k = e$, hence the set (actually an ideal) $\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid a^n=e\}$ is exactly the same as the set $\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid (a^{-1})^n = e\}$. Since the order of $a$ is the nonnegative generator of this ideal, we conclude that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same order. Alternatively, if the order is the cardinality of $\langle a\rangle$, note that $a\in\langle a^{-1}\rangle$ and $a^{-1}\in\langle a\rangle$, hence $\langle a \rangle = \langle a^{-1}\rangle$.